Confusing to read the list of middleware in appModule NESTJS
How do you all organize a long list of middlewares with conditional routing conditions?
What are some of the best practices for this? I've read the nestjs documentation on middleware but I feel like doesn't apply well for a larger app with multi middleware.
How do yall do it?

Can you describe the problem in more detailed way?
